# How to get URL of Default Action in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to get URL of the default controller's default action method link, such that if I change default controller and action in route config then should be updated in the view too.
e.g.

```
  Url.Action(defaultAction,DefaultController);
//output should be like
Url.Action("Index","Home")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the default route is named `Default` (in your `RoutesConfig`):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

You can use `Url.RouteUrl` to get the url:

```
Url.RouteUrl("Default")
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.RouteUrl%28System.String%29)